# How to get attribute values that doesn't contain numbers?

Tags: regex, string, numbers, numeric

I have created automation test code for one website. And I am collecting all the links that are not contains numeric values in it. For an Ex.

correct link ex:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

link that I want to exclude ex:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12

My code is:

```
List<WebElement> AllTheLinkList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

for (WebElement link : AllTheLinkList) {
            breakIt = true;
            try {

                if (link.getAttribute("href") != null &&  link.getAttribute("href").contains("pharmacy")
                         && !link.getAttribute("href").endsWith("pharmacy/main#"))
                {
                    activeLinks.add(link);
                }

            } catch (org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
                breakIt = false;
            }
            if (breakIt) {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

I want to add to if() condition something with regex so that the if condition exclude the link that are ends with numbers.

```
!link.getAttribute("href").matches(regex expression)
```

Comment: `!link.getAttribute("href").matches(".*/\\d+$")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes this is working. Thank you!